# JGit : How to get Branch when traversing repos

Tags: git, branch, commit, traversal, jgit

The lacking JGit docs dont seem to say anything about how to use/detect branches while using a RevWalk.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039558/jgit-retrieve-branch-on-which-a-commitid-was-made) says pretty much the same thing.

So my question is:  How do I get the branch name/id from a RevCommit?  Or how do I specify which branch to traverse before hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out a better way to do it by looping branches.

I looped over the branches by calling

```
for (Ref branch : git.branchList().call()){
    git.checkout().setName(branch.getName()).call();
    // Then just revwalk as normal.
}
```

Comment: +1 no the traversing a single branch. My answer was more about finding the branch given a commit.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the current implementation of JGit (see [its git repo](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/) and its [RevCommit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.java) class), I didn't find the equivalent of what is listed in "[Git: Finding what branch a commit came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from)".
Ie:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Only some of the options of `git branch` are implemented (like in [`ListBranchCommand.java`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListBranchCommand.java)).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is no support for going from commit -> branch, but do you know if traversing only a single branch's commits is possible?

Comment: +1 because your answer helped me get in the right direction.  Interesting to see exactly what they implemented.

Answer (score 1):

could use below code to get "from" branch by commit:

```
/**
     * find out which branch that specified commit come from.
     * 
     * @param commit
     * @return branch name.
     * @throws GitException 
     */
    public String getFromBranch(RevCommit commit) throws GitException{
        try {
            Collection<ReflogEntry> entries = git.reflog().call();
            for (ReflogEntry entry:entries){
                if (!entry.getOldId().getName().equals(commit.getName())){
                    continue;
                }

                CheckoutEntry checkOutEntry = entry.parseCheckout();
                if (checkOutEntry != null){
                    return checkOutEntry.getFromBranch();
                }
            }

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GitException("fail to get ref log.", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting but I suspect it wouldn't scale for a large repository.